Connecting vcenter using yavi java in springboot
I am trying to connect vcenter via spring boot, when i fill the details in serviceInstance like url, username , password, ignorecert is true/ false it is not connecting with vcenter null pointer exception is coming can you guys help me out.
This error i am getting vmware.vim25.ws.client.setVimNameSpace(String) because the return value of com.vmware.vim25.vimportType.getWsc() is null
Expected someone try to give me cause and solution.

Not without any code. How are the url, username, etc. getting in there?
